# Should we keep downvoted answers for the mistakeful information?

Tags: discussion, answers

It is my understanding that answers which are downvoted should be removed because they are considered noise and not useful. These kinds of answers should be edited to correct the inaccuracies or be deleted. However, these answers often contain useful information in the comments explaining why the answer is bad or wrong. Sometimes a more correct and higher upvoted answer could say:

> Another answerer said so-and-so... However, you shouldn't follow this
>   advice because *insert reasons here*... Rest of answer follows.

In my opinion, this kind of information is still useful even though it doesn't directly pertain to answering the question. If the mistake is easily derived, say due to the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), or exists in a long list of answers in a historical question (where the upvotes have accumulated due to age), then the comments are especially helpful here.

To invert the above answer, imagine another answer which says:

> On top of what so-and-so said, if you are going to follow their approach,
>   you should watch out for *insert problem here*... Here's my approach.

I imagine that these kinds of answers are acceptable because they contain an alternate approach to the problem.

But could answers which are wrong ever be useful simply because it's an indication of the mistake to avoid?

Answer (score 9):

I tend to find these useful, especially if I'm starting out with something new. You have [language], you want to try connecting to a database and run some queries, and you *think* you know how to do it, but you do a quick search just in case ...

Lo and behold, you find a question about it with a *great* answer, followed by a down-voted answer which basically describes the approach you were about to take. It's a great way to figure out where you were going wrong in your original thinking, and help you think more along the lines of the [language] way.

That's of course assuming it's an otherwise fine answer, just *wrong*. If it's a terse sentence with a link, or has other quality issues, then removal should be considered on the grounds of that alone, not the fact that it's wrong or misleading.

Bad information, when properly identified and labeled, can be just as helpful as good information. You don't see too many of these left around any longer, folks generally self-delete answers with negative scores unless they find some useful purpose for keeping them (and the rep the lost on them) around.

Comment: Yup, you put it perfectly. The problem is exacerbated if the misunderstanding exists with the question asker (i.e., they ask on another answer a question that was explained by the comments on the bad, now deleted answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no convention of deleting answers simply because they might be erroneous. The only correct action to take is to downvote the answer, unless it falls into one of the flag criteria, in which case you should obviously flag it.

Wrong answers, whilst annoying, do offer an opportunity for others to learn about how **not** to go about a problem. Sometimes an answer is functionally correct, but uses deprecated functions or extensions (like the often used, but deprecated, `mysql_` extension in PHP), and answers like these are prime candidates for writing comments about the use of better alternatives, or better coding practice.